# Пустой reqest в Java Servlet, проблемы с GSON

Tags: java, json, servlet, request, gson

**Есть вот такой код на бакэнде:**

```
public class testServ extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter printWriter = resp.getWriter();
    iLog iLog = new iLog();
    System.out.println(req.getHeader("phone"));
    System.out.println(req.getParameter("phone"));
    System.out.println(req.getParameterMap().get("phone"));
    System.out.println(req.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator())));
}

@Override
protected void doPut(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
}
```

**И вот такой на фронте:**

```
    public void initRequest(final String phone, final String password){
    JSONObject param = new JSONObject();
    try {
        param.put("phone",phone);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, param, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
          Log.d("TEST",response.toString());
         }
     }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
      @Override
      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
          Log.d("tester",error.toString());
      }
  });
      queue.add(request);
    System.out.println(param.toString());
}
```

На фронте стоит VOLLEY.

Проблема в том, что как бы я мучал фронт, на бакэнде у меня получается хоть что-то забрать из реквеста только последним методом.

`getHeader` и `getParam` если к VOLLEY прописать тоже `null` при любом раскладе кроме последнего.

Я бы особо не жаловался и распарсил на бакэнде все это дело библиотекой GSON, но когда я просто создаю ее экземпляр в сервлете, почему-то все падает. Единственное, что пишет это на фронте, мол ошибка сервера, хотя на бакэнде не выбивает никакой стэктрейс.

Помогите понять что не так с GSON или что я делаю не так, почему я не могу забрать данные любым из способов кроме последнего на бакэнде.

Answer (score 0):

В заголовке вы ничего не отправляете json, а в теле реквеста. Если такой сспособ чтения из тела реквеста вам подходит, то вы можете вернуть то, что распарсили в объект. В данном случае надо написать `toString()` чтобы вернуть объект с сервера.

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
   String list1 = req.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
   System.out.println(list1);
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   iLog iLog = gson.fromJson(list1, iLog.class);
   resp.setContentType("text/plain");
   resp.getWriter().write(String.valueOf(iLog); 
}
```